# How can I detect tag in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want make my bot delete any tag that tag me, but it doesn't work. It work successful in random word but failed in tag such as <@id>.

```
bot.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("")) { //what should I write in ""?
    message.delete()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the bot was mentioned using [`Message#mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions).

```js
if (message.mentions.users.has(bot.user.id)) {
  message.delete()
}
```

Note that this also counts for replies that mention the user. If you want to check the message content, but not replies, you can use regex

```js
const regex = new RegExp(`<@!?${bot.user.id}>`)
if (regex.test(message.content)) {
  message.delete()
}
```

Comment: Oh, no! I use USERS_PATTERN to code, but my bot start to delete every message in server,  I just want to detect only my id, am I wrong to use USERS_PATTERN?

Comment: Yes, that's meant to give you all mentions